# How to include multiple parameters in sqlmap POST request

Tags: penetration-test, sqlmap

I'm using the following command to inject the `Username` parameter:

```
sqlmap -r Path_Of_Myfile -p UserName
```

It's running well. But there's also a second parameter of `Password`. How can I also attempt to inject the `Password` parameters in sqlmap?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just comma-separate the parameters you want to test.

In a GET request:

```
$ sqlmap -u "http://example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3" -p "a,b"
```

In a POST request:

```
$ sqlmap -u "http://example.com/" --data "a=1&b=2&c=3" -p "a,b" --method POST
...
[13:37:54] [WARNING] heuristic (basic) test shows that POST parameter 'a' might not be injectable
...
[13:37:59] [WARNING] heuristic (basic) test shows that POST parameter 'b' might not be injectable
...
```

Both examples would test the specified parameters `a` and `b`, but ignore `c`. (I also put them into double quotes which isn't actually necessary on Linux.)